# chrome.storage.local.get возвращает пустой массив

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension

Столкнулся с проблемой, и не могу решить ее самостоятельно(

Если вызвать функцию IncCounter() то счетчик Settings.Data.CountData[date] будет успешно увеличен.

Затем вызываем функцию save(), затем load(). Если верить переменной Settings.Data.someBool функции отрабатывают (Значения someBool  сохраняются и загружаются как надо).

Но вот массив CountData в Load() прилетает пустой. Что не так с этим массивом?

```
let Settings = {
  Data: {
    someBool: false,
    CountData: []
  }}


  function save(){
    chrome.storage.local.set({ SettingsData: Settings.Data }, function () {
      console.debug("Save()");
    });
    }

function load() {
  chrome.storage.local.get(['SettingsData'], function (result) {
    console.debug("Load()");

    if (!result.SettingsData) {
      console.debug("Init");
      save();
      return;
    }

    Settings.Data = result.SettingsData;

    console.debug(Settings.Data);

  });
}

function IncCounter() {


  let today = new Date();
  let date = "Date-" + today.getFullYear() + '-' + (today.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + today.getDate();


  if (Settings.Data.CountData[date] === undefined) {
    Settings.Data.CountData[date] = 0;
  }

  Settings.Data.CountData[date]++;

  save();
}
```

UPD:

Спасибо участнику с ником vsemozhetbyt, я пытался обращаться к элементам массива как к свойствам объекта. Отсюда и все проблемы.

Comment: Кажется, вы определяете переменную как массив, а потом обращаетесь с ней, как с объектом. Конечно, массив является объектом в общем смысле. Но от того, что вы присваиваете ему свойства, сам массив не перестаёт быть пустым. Попробуйте определить его как объект: `CountData: {}`

Comment: @vsemozhetbyt Спасибо большое так и есть, свято верил что могу создавать и обращаться к элементам массива используя строки. И ведь даже проверку делал в консоли браузера                                                  
`let arr = []; arr['q'] = 1; arr['w'] = 23`

Comment: Вы можете, но в таком случае вы используете базовое поведение массива как объекта. Однако с этими значениями не будут работать ни специальные методы массива (map, filter и т.д.), ни итерирование типа for...of.

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендую к прочтению\использованию:

1. библиотека - [промисы для chrome api](https://github.com/KeithHenry/chromeExtensionAsync#readme)
2. [стрелочные функции, шаблонные строки и многое другое](https://habr.com/ru/post/305900/), для того чтобы писать код **чище** и **лучше**
3. [верблюд](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase), *которого любят даже дети*, а именно [lowerCamelCase](https://www.google.ru/search?q=lowerCamelCase), *#javascript не java*
4. [сайт - учебник](https://learn.javascript.ru/), имеет со 2 пункта штуки, и чек 11 пункты

+Немного рефактора/примера в студию:

```js
const settings = {
    data: {
        someBool: false,
        countData: [],
    },
};

const set=async(akey, obj)=>{
    try{
        await chrome.storage.local.set({[akey]: obj});
        return true;
    }catch(e){
        console.log(e);
        return false;
    }
};

const get=async(pmt)=>{
    if(pmt === false)return false;
    const tmp = await chrome.storage.local.get([pmt]);
    return tmp[pmt] ? tmp[pmt] : false;
};

(async()=>{
    let date = new Date();
    date = `Date: ${date.getFullYear()} - ${(date.getMonth()+1+'').padStart(2, '0')} - ${(date.getDate()+'').padStart(2, '0')}`;
    console.log(date);

    let r = 'some';

    r = await set('SettingsData', settings.data);
    console.log('saved', (r !== false ? '+' : '-'));
    if(!r)return false;

    r = await get('SettingsData');
    console.log('loaded:', r);
    if(!r)return false;

    // init();
})();
```